# has anyone written a nodejs server side component to listen only for Ethereum Events?

Tags: blockchain, nodejs

I tried the below code to run it using the `pm2 module`, as `nohup` command as well. But, this doesn't seem to work. I saw [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2191/how-can-i-setup-a-web3-webservice-that-listens-for-events-from-my-smart-contract), but no code is present. so this is what I'm trying to accomplish.

I want to run this piece of code as a daemon on the server so that it can listen for the incoming event coming from the Ethereum Blockchain.

```
Web3   = require("web3");
web3   = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/jusRXXXXXXLnnNk"));

address="0x1fe.....3";
abi=[....];
var myContractInstance  = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);
function event(){
var event = myContractInstance.Sent({},function(error, result) {
    if (!error) {
          var msg = result.args.from +" sent  " + result.args.amount + " coins to " + result.args.to;
          console.log(msg);
    }
    else {
        console.error(error);
    } 
});
}

event();
```

I tried keeping the code without the event() as well like this:

```
Web3   = require("web3");
web3   = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/jusRXXXXXXLnnNk"));

address="0x1fe.....3";
abi=[....];
var myContractInstance  = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);

var event = myContractInstance.Sent({},function(error, result) {
    if (!error) {
          var msg = result.args.from +" sent  " + result.args.amount + " coins to " + result.args.to;
          console.log(msg);
    }
    else {
        console.error(error);
    } 
});
```

Can anyone help on this with the instruction on what I'm missing here?

Edit 1: I'm using `emit` in the event as well. here's the updated [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/J2cw6feT).

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: pm2 make sure that it keeps running in the background, but when I do the transaction in the remix and generate the event, I can't see anything on the console or the stdout file.

Comment: which network are you using?

Comment: Ropsten. I'm using infura API to link it

Comment: using https://pastebin.com/UpwGMGaD code. because, if I can listen for this event, I can listen'em all.

Comment: I think I would confirm assumptions by calling a function, just to make sure it's happily instantiated. Also, are you using Web3 Beta 1 by any chance? The format has changed a little: http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#events

Comment: Until some time ago infura didn't support the required methods to listen events. You had to use something like a filter provider from the [MetaMask's provider engine](https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine).

Comment: Okay. So here's the thing. How to do that(use metamask) in nodejs? Means how do i inject web3 object in nodejs without infura. Do i need to run my own fullnode synced with ropsten?  I want to listen to contract events in nodejs. Can you help with some code?