# Is there a provision to inform smart contract deployer of the function call on that contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js

I have a scenario like this. I am creating a private blockchain for non financial purpose. If I deploy a contract from one node (owner of pets) of the network which contains a mapping of `pets ID` and `adopter address`(initally set to empty addresses). Whenever someone calls the `placeAdoptRequest(petID)` function of the smart contract. Is there a way the smart contract owner be informed of this request, so that they call a function `changePetOwner(petID, address)` from their side to set the adopter address corresponding to the pet they choose.

Comment: Related: [How can i setup a web3 webservice that listens for events from my smart contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2191/how-can-i-setup-a-web3-webservice-that-listens-for-events-from-my-smart-contract?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am also looking for similar problem. I am new to smart contracts and ethereum, can you please point to some tutorial or sample code that helps me understand how to develop such js file.

Comment: Hi there. Lesson 6 of CryptoZombies covers how to register for and filter events in a JS front-end. https://cryptozombies.io/ (You'll need to complete the first five lessons first.)

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. that tutorial looks pretty interesting, but need lot of time though. Anyways, I will go through it.